# Can you get a vrius from URLConnection getting code from a webpage?

Tags: java, security

I am making a program that goes to websites and extracts information and in worried about security. This is the code I use:

```
public String GetPageCode(String url) throws IOException{
    URL page = new URL(url);
    URLConnection con = page.openConnection();
    con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); // Avoids most filters that block out computers
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(inputLine);
    in.close();

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Is there a threat of downloading a virus or malicious file with this code?

Comment: Not unless you download *and execute* executable code.

Comment: Thanks for making me less paranoid!

Comment: Not what you think but it's certainly not impossible. You're connecting to an untrusted system and lots of functions parse the data it sends you (e.g. http headers). Like all with all parsers, it is possible that malformed input triggers an exploitable bug, worst case one that enables the attacker to execute arbitrary code on your machine. https://ma.ttias.be/remote-code-execution-via-http-request-in-iis-on-windows/

Comment: @zapl As the parser is written in Java, you wont get an exploitable bug like that. You may get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, `OutOfMemoryError` or something like that. On the other hand, the application may do something silly with the returned data or headers. Execute as JavaScript for instance.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline It could be enough to save the string to disc in order to open a security hole: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=820  Who knows if there are circumstances where even processing the string inside the jvm could be harmful.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline yes, the typical bufferoverflow won't happen at jls defined / bytecode level, but under there is still native memory and the JVM / native libraries used by it can have bugs or JIT could produce faulty code. Aren't timezone abbreviations handled in native code? Unicode things (like the unicode of death that could take down iphones)? It's theoretical but I wouldn't call it impossible

Comment: @zapl I'd be more worried about cosmic rays. Bugs in the JVM itself tend to affect only malicious code, though there have been odd exceptions (dealing with > 2GB arrays on some configurations and the optimisation that affected Apache hash tries IIRC). There's not much native code there for a sensible implementation other than dealing with the socket. Timezones willl have used native configuration on initialisation. Unicode handling will be done in Java for this (modified Unicode used in class loading will be native on normal implementations). gzip springs to mind.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I'm not worried. But I also don't want to be around the day someone discovers a code execution vulnerability triggerable by plain `URLConnection`s.

Comment: @zapl Then the only thing for it is an air gap. (But watch out for USB devices.)